# How to get xindy work with Texmaker and Miktex?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, indexing, xindy

I would like to use xindy with Texmaker, but it doesn't work.

I have Perl version 5 installed on my computer and xindy also seems to be well installed since it is recognized in the windows command prompt and Miktex indicates that it is installed.

[image]

[image]

If I compile the following MWE, here are the errors I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Blah blah blah\index{A}\index{W}\index{E}\index{À}\index{É}\index{R}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to replace "makeindex %.idx" by "xindy %" but it does not change anything.

[image]

Please, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the command line, `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex`  works in TeX Live. MikTeX may be similar.